# WPF Designer ONLY: NullReferenceException when loading connection string from app.config

Tags: wpf, designer, nullreferenceexception

Please help, for the sake of my non-pulled out hair...

The following code line:

```
this._connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

is causing me untold amounts of grief.

It is in a user control, currently in the control's Loaded event but I've also tried the constructor and just plain initializing the field to the value when it's declared. Whenever I do so, the WPF designer pitches a fit on any screen that uses said user control.

The code itself compiles fine, and runs with no issues. But it's turning into a real hampering in development not being able to use the designer at all. Does anyone have any clue what could cause this and a hint as to a good practice to avoid it in the future? I suspect it has something to do with trying to access the ConfigurationManager but I can't figure out where to put the line to make it stop.

Thanks.

PS: Visual Studio 2010 Premium

Comment: Segmenting your data layer from your User Control (perhaps by putting it in the model of an M-V-VM or MVC architecture) could prevent this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're working in design time, you should avoid loading this.  Fill in the value with some other, appropriate default, instead:

```
if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
    this._connectionString = "Default";
else
{
    this._connectionString = ConfigurationManager
                              .ConnectionStrings["SqlConnectionString"]
                              .ConnectionString;
}
```

Comment: Not working. It still keeps going and tries to parse "Default" and then says unable to parse or some nonsense. So I put in a valid but broken connection string and it actually attempted to connect with it and failed.

Comment: @zk812: You need to make your connection not connect at design time, as well.

Comment: How has this never been a problem before VS2010? All my VS2008 WPF apps follow this same pattern with no issue...

Comment: @zk812: This isn't typically a problem for most controls, as they rarely "do" something at design time.  You're trying to connect to a DB at load time (which is not a very good WPF thing to do - MVVM would help a lot here), which causes VS to try to connect at design time.

Answer (score 1):

The designer probably isn't looking at your app's configuration but rather at the configuration of its current host app (VS), and so ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlConnectionString"] returns null at design-time.

Answer (score 0):

This restriction is similar to what is see in MVC applications whereby the Web.Config doesn't get instantiated at design time. Lo...WPF does the same thing whereby the App.Config is not present at design time.